# Masking out Interpolated Data over Ocean

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I need to mask out data over oceans/water so that only data over the land is visible. Below is a sample of the matplotlib script that I am using. This data is interpolated via `griddata()`.

**Python Script:**

```
def mapformat():

  m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-85,llcrnrlat=36.5,urcrnrlon=-64,urcrnrlat=47.5,
        projection='lcc',lat_1=33,lat_2=45,lon_0=-70,lon_1=-60, resolution='h')
  # resolution c, l, i, h, f in that order

  m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua', zorder=-1)
  m.fillcontinents(color='green', lake_color='aqua', zorder=0)

  m.drawcounties(color='0.1', linewidth=0.05, antialiased=True)
  m.drawcoastlines(color='0.0', linewidth=0.25, antialiased=True)
  m.drawcountries(color='0.0', linewidth=0.5, antialiased=True)
  m.drawstates(color='0.0', linewidth=0.25, antialiased=True)
  #m.drawparallels(np.arange(35.,45.,5), labels=[1,0,0,1], dashes=[1,1], linewidth=0.25, color='0.5')
  #m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0., 360., 5.), labels=[1,0,0,1], dashes=[1,1], linewidth=0.25, color='0.5')

  return m

data = np.loadtxt('/home/.../.../.../maxs', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)

m = mapformat()

dx = 0.25

grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[-85:-60:dx, 34:50:dx] #Northeast

temp = data[:,0]

#print temp

figure = plt.gcf() # get current figure
figure.set_size_inches(8, 4.5)

grid_z = griddata((data[:,2],data[:,1]), data[:,0], (grid_x,grid_y), method='cubic')

x,y = m(data[:,2], data[:,1]) # flip lat/lon

grid_x,grid_y = m(grid_x,grid_y)

#m.plot(x,y, 'ko', markersize=2)

for i in range(len(temp)):
    fmt=r"%.f" % (temp[i])
    #plt.text(x[i], y[i], fmt, va="center", ha="center", fontsize='12')
    plt.annotate(fmt,xy=(x[i], y[i]), xytext=None, va="center", ha="center", fontsize="3")

    clevs1 =[-30,-29,-28,-27,-26,-25,-24,-23,-22,-21, -20,    -19,-18,-17,-16,-15,-14,-13,-12,-11,-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,
19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,
58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,
98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110]

custom = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list( 'own2', [ltsilver,medblue,darkpurple,brightpink,medred,white,
medblue,cyan,medgreen,yellow,orange,red,darkred,darkpeach,ltsilver] )

m.contourf(grid_x,grid_y,grid_z,clevs1,cmap=custom)
```

**Plot Sample:**

[image: ne.png]

I have read that masking out can be achieved via `is_land` in basemap but I'm not sure if it will work with interpolated data. Also, there are no data points over the oceans/water.

Answer (score 0):

I remember trying to do something similar. I'll post what I can, but this comes from digging up old code.

The key steps seem to be:

1. Get a good land/sea boundary
2. Make a Polygon object out of it
3. Add the Polygon to the axes
4. Plot your data, using the keywords `clip_path` and `clip_on`.

The particular code segment I have is

```
USPatch = mpl.patch.Polygon(USXY, facecolor='none', edgecolor='none')
ax.add_patch(USPatch)
im = bm.pcolormesh(lonE, latE, data,
                   ax=ax, clip_path=USPatch, clip_on=True, zorder=1)
im.set_clip_path(USPatch)
```

where `USXY` is a `numpy` array for the US border and `bm` is my Basemap object. I think I got `USXY` from `bm.drawcoastlines().get_segments()`, but I don't know (or don't remember) how to go from line segments to a good, complete boundary.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to make a minimal working example from snippets of old code alone. Try parsing [this on Basemap and clipping](http://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/clip.html).